# How to efficiently remove nodes that do not connect two different nodes of a targeted type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database with relationships like : `(:Person)-[:KNOWS]-(:Target)`

**I would like to remove all Persons that are not connected to at least two different Targets** thanks to a Cypher query.

I tried to use a query that, for each node, get all connected nodes (with an arbitrary path length) and then count the number of Target in it. If there is less than two, I remove the node.
But the request seems to be extremely long and unsuccessful:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[*]-(t:Target)
WITH n, COUNT(t) AS nb_targets
WHERE NOT n:Target AND nb_targets < 2
RETURN n
```

The request does not even succeed due to its inefficiency...

NB : I have only a few Targets and a lot of Persons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher is interested in returning all possible paths that match the pattern, so it won't do well with an unbounded variable-length query like this.

You can instead use the [path expander procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), which are designed to be more efficient for these use cases. We can even limit the results per node to 2, since that's the minimum we would need to determine if a node needs to be kept or discarded.

If you needed a query just to return those that didn't have at least 2 targets, then this query should work:

```
MATCH (n:Person)
WHERE NOT n:TARGET
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n, {labelFilter:'>TARGET', limit:2, optional:true}) YIELD node
WITH n, count(node) AS nb_targets
WHERE nb_targets < 2
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer ! It worked perfectly and very effectively.
I just had to replace `'>TARGET'` by `'TARGET'` in the cypher query (small typing mistake I think).

Comment: That wasn't a typo, that's part of the syntax for using the [label filter](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_label_filter). Without any preceding symbol it's a whitelist filter, so all nodes traversed must have the label. With the preceding `>` symbol it's an end node label filter, meaning it will expand nodes of any label, but the proc will only YIELD nodes with the given label. In this case, it will expand out to all reachable :TARGET nodes at any distance and yield them (limiting to 2 per starting node).

Comment: Well, I had completely missed it, thank you very much for the precision.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

If this is a real-life scenario (say, identifying suspects who might be in cahoots with known bad guys), then you probably don't care about people who have a large "degree of separation" from the bad guys. Otherwise, you may end up with most of the population falling under suspicion. So, you will probably want to impose a reasonable upper bound on the depth of your search.

It just so happens that the time (and memory) required to search a variable length path goes up exponentially with the depth of the search, so to speed up the search you would want to impose a reasonable upper bound on the depth of the search as well.

Therefore, try using a reasonable upper bound (say, 6). Here is a query to identify people who are not themselves targets and who are connected (by up to a depth of 6) to fewer than 2 targets. To help speed up the search, I also limit the search to just using `KNOWS` relationships (assuming that is the only relationship type you care about). And note that I count `DISTINCT` targets, since multiple paths can contain the same target.

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE NOT n:Target
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:KNOWS*..6]-(t:Target)
WITH n, COUNT(DISTINCT t) AS nb_targets
WHERE nb_targets < 2
RETURN n
```

To eliminate all the people who are not potential suspects (including the ones who are more than 6 hops from any target), then you can first identify all the suspects and delete the people who are neither targets nor suspects:

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE NOT n:Target
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[:KNOWS*..6]-(t:Target)
WITH n, COUNT(DISTINCT t) AS nb_targets
WHERE nb_targets >= 2
WITH COLLECT(n) AS suspects
MATCH (m:Person)
WHERE NOT m:Target AND NOT m IN suspects
DETACH DELETE m
```

Comment: Just keep in mind the size(<pattern>) approach may count multiple paths to a single :Target, this wouldn't be accurate enough to determine if they're connected to at least two distinct targets.